# Youtube-dl error messages & infinite looping

Tags: youtube-dl

I've used `youtube-dl` successfully for quite a while, until recently. Now it seems to me to be useless for grabbing videos off of YouTube or Odysee, which are the only platforms I really use.

I have already tried uninstalling & reinstalling.

Here are the error messages; similar errors occur regardless of the way I format the command, or which video I'm attempting to grab.

Here is an example from Odysee:

```
will@will-Inspiron-15-7579:~$ youtube-dl https://odysee.com/@betterthanfood:4/brave-new-world-aldous-huxley-book:f
[generic] brave-new-world-aldous-huxley-book:f: Requesting header
WARNING: Falling back on generic information extractor.
[generic] brave-new-world-aldous-huxley-book:f: Downloading webpage
[generic] brave-new-world-aldous-huxley-book:f: Extracting information
[generic] f0338bc5ed0263d3832d5288807d43fb222e0a10?: Requesting header
[redirect] Following redirect to https://odysee.com/$/embed/brave-new-world-aldous-huxley-book/f0338bc5ed0263d3832d5288807d43fb222e0a10
[generic] f0338bc5ed0263d3832d5288807d43fb222e0a10: Requesting header
WARNING: Falling back on generic information extractor.
[generic] f0338bc5ed0263d3832d5288807d43fb222e0a10: Downloading webpage
[generic] f0338bc5ed0263d3832d5288807d43fb222e0a10: Extracting information
[generic] f0338bc5ed0263d3832d5288807d43fb222e0a10?: Requesting header
[redirect] Following redirect to https://odysee.com/$/embed/brave-new-world-aldous-huxley-book/f0338bc5ed0263d3832d5288807d43fb222e0a10
[generic] f0338bc5ed0263d3832d5288807d43fb222e0a10: Requesting header
WARNING: Falling back on generic information extractor.
[generic] f0338bc5ed0263d3832d5288807d43fb222e0a10: Downloading webpage
^C
ERROR: Interrupted by user
```

As you can see, this command triggered infinite recursion/iteration which would have continued indefinitely; I had to manually terminate the program with `CTRL+C`

Here's an example from Youtube, which has a different problem:

```
will@will-Inspiron-15-7579:~$ youtube-dl https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U5afsxvz75c
[youtube] U5afsxvz75c: Downloading webpage
[youtube] U5afsxvz75c: Downloading video info webpage
WARNING: unable to download video info webpage: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
WARNING: unable to download video info webpage: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
WARNING: unable to download video info webpage: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
WARNING: unable to download video info webpage: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
WARNING: unable to download video info webpage: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/youtube-dl", line 6, in <module>
    youtube_dl.main()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/youtube_dl/__init__.py", line 476, in main
    _real_main(argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/youtube_dl/__init__.py", line 466, in _real_main
    retcode = ydl.download(all_urls)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py", line 1989, in download
    url, force_generic_extractor=self.params.get('force_generic_extractor', False))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py", line 785, in extract_info
    ie_result = ie.extract(url)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/youtube_dl/extractor/common.py", line 440, in extract
    ie_result = self._real_extract(url)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/youtube_dl/extractor/youtube.py", line 1607, in _real_extract
    token = video_info.get('token') or video_info.get('account_playback_token')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Again, I just uninstalled and reinstalled `youtube-dl` using `apt`, so this should be the latest version. Output of `youtube-dl --version` is `2018.03.14`.

Thanks for any help you may be able to provide :)

Comment: Assuming this is on a unix system -- you *do* have the entire url in single quotes, don't you?

Comment: It's a bash shell. Enclosing the URL in single quotes results in the same behavior as I described in OP. In the past, when youtube-dl was still working for me, it was never necessary to enclose the URL in quotes.

Answer (score 6):

You are using a very outdated version. First, uninstall apt package, then run:
`sudo curl -L https://yt-dl.org/downloads/latest/youtube-dl -o /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl`
and
`sudo chmod a+rx /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl`
Latest version is now `2021-05-16`, and works well with your URL

Comment: Note is -O and not -o

Comment: but works with -o. Thanks for new version, apt - broken!